how to watch a ref in a composable for updates with Vue 3?
I’m trying to understand a specific issue. I have a composable in Vue 3 that needs to watch a reference, which gets updated in the view through a text field. How can I set up a watcher on this variable to trigger the watch?
 export function useFieldValidationHelper3<T>(fieldValue: Ref<T>) {
 const value = fieldValue;

watch(
 value.value,
 (newValue) => {
   newValue.value = value;
   console.log("Field value updated in the composable", newValue);
 },
 { deep: true }
);

const errorMessage: Ref<string | undefined> = ref("");
const field = ref();
console.log(fieldValue)
// Method to manually update the value if needed
function updateValue(newValue: T) {
 console.log("VALIDATE IS UPDATING THE HOUSE NUMBER", newValue);
 field.value = newValue;
} 

const getValue = computed(() => {
 return value;
});


return {
 fieldValue,
 errorMessage,
 updateValue,
 getValue
};
}

The view
import { useFieldValidationHelper3   } from "@/composables/FieldValidationHelper3";

const testValue = ref({
      houseNumber: '1'
    });

const { fieldValue, errorMessage, updateValue, getValue } = useFieldValidationHelper3(testValue.value.houseNumber);

// This is not the preferred way
const updateText = () => {
  updateValue(getValue.value+"1");
}

... Some more HTML
<v-text-field hide-details="auto" label="House Number" v-model="testValue.houseNumber" class="noBorders"></v-text-field>
{{ fieldValue, errorMessage, updateValue, getValue }} 
<button @click="updateText">Test </button>


I’m confident that I’m nearing a solution.
Best,
Ido

There are several problems.
A value is being instantly read in the composable, this defies the purpose of using a ref and it couldn't be made reactive this way in JavaScript.
It should be either:
watch(() => value.value, ...)

Or, since watch specifically supports refs for this use:
watch(value, ...)

There's a problem with variable naming, because value isn't a value but value reference. If a parameter is allowed to be both a value and a ref, it could be fieldValueOrRef for clarity.
At the place where a value is consumed it can be:
const fieldValue = toValue(fieldValueOrRef);

In the case of a computed or watcher this should happen inside a function, but it doesn't serve a good purpose to set up a watcher for non-reactive value, so in this case a watcher should've been made optional depending on the provided value.
Instantly reading a value like useFieldValidationHelper3(testValue.value.houseNumber) is the same as useFieldValidationHelper3(1), and again, it cannot be made reactive this way. In order to do this, the argument should be a ref (could be a computed in this case). But to the associated boilerplate, it can also be a getter function that is commonly used for computed, etc to lazily read a value. This is the reason toValue accepts both refs and getter functions, this allows to unify the usage in an efficient way. A getter function prevents useFieldValidationHelper3 from exposing its own model as single source of truth, but this shouldn't be a problem because a model already exists in the context where useFieldValidationHelper3 is used, this makes getValue and updateValue not useful.
So a composable with external model could be:
function useFieldValidationHelper3<T>(fieldGetterOrRef: Ref<T> | () => T) {

  if (isRef(fieldGetterOrRef) or typeof fieldGetterOrRef === 'function') {
    watch(() => toValue(fieldGetterOrRef), value => ...)
  } else {
    // composable doesn't do anything useful
  }
  ...

With a possible use:
const { errorMessage } = useFieldValidationHelper3(() => testValue.value.houseNumber);
const updateText = () => {
  testValue.value.houseNumber = 2
}

And a composable that accepts an initial value and has optional internal model could be:
function useFieldValidationHelper3<T>(fieldValueOrRef: MaybeRef<T>) {

  let fieldRef: Ref<T>;

  if (isRef(fieldValueOrRef)) {
    // external model
    if (isReadonly(fieldValueOrRef))
      throw new Error()
    fieldRef = fieldValueOrRef;
  } else {
    // internal model
    fieldRef = ref(fieldValueOrRef);
  }

  watch(fieldRef, value => ...);
  ...
  return { fieldRef, ... }
}

With a possible use:
const houseNumberRef = ref(1);

const testValue = ref({ houseNumber: houseNumberRef });

const { errorMessage, fieldRef } = seFieldValidationHelper3(houseNumberRef);
const updateText = () => {
  fieldRef.value = 2 // or houseNumberRef
}

Either way, no need for separate getValue and updateValue, this is what reactive objects do. And fieldRef that a composable returns is redundant when there's external model.

Okey after some trail and error I found something,
When i use toRefs(testValue).houseNumber it seems to work.
But still I have no idea why this is working, how this is working underwater and if this hits the performance.

The problem with toRefs(testValue) in your case is that testValue itself is a ref, so if it's fully reassigned,  toRefs(testValue).houseNumber refers to old object. And if testValue is reactive(), you lose the ability to cleanly reassign current value, e.g by updating it from remote api. You'd need a writable computed({ set(v) { (testValue.value.houseNumber = v }, get: () => testValue.value.houseNumber }) to make it consistent, or rethink how you deal with models to make this cleaner
